# Play Count and Last Played date not updating from devices

Tags: iphone, itunes, icloud, music

I use Apple Music and iCloud Music Library (and iTunes Match). In the past my play counts from my devices update the shared library. I use this for my smart playlists.

But lately they update only on the first song I play in a session on a device and then no more updating from that device for like a day. I see the play counts and last played dates in iTunes on my PC. The devices are otherwise fully in sync. Adding a new song or deleting a song updates between the PC and other devices quickly. It's just song plays that don't.

Others are seeing this same behavior: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254356266

For me it's happening on my iPhone, iPad, and Apple TV 4K, all attached to my iCloud Music Library. So it's unlikely to be a device setting issue.

Does this happen for everyone? Can anyone confirm that it's currently working for them with a setup like mine?

I've tried deleting all the songs in my library to try to get it to reset my library, but no luck. Perhaps because I still have purchased songs and movies? Not sure.

What are all the ways to approach this problem? What more experiments can I try? What's the best way to enlist Apple to fix it? What more settings can I check?